# How to see the variable values in flutter debug

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable inside a Provider which I want to see its value (because its value is cleaning and I don't know why) in debug, but I don't know how to see it.

How can I debug seeing this variable value while I'm navigating in the app??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest create setter for that variable and use it everywhere in your code (where this variable is changed).
Then place brakepoint to this setter. This way you will be able to track whenever variable is changed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place breakpoint
2. Run in Debug mode (F5 is the shortcut for VSCode)
3. Open the window 'Debug Console' (Found in the 'View' menu in VS code)
4. Type in the variable name in the command prompt

The variable representation is printed on the console. You can click, browse and navigate the data structure as well.

Answer (score 0):

put debug point where the value of provider is used,
or you can use flutter devtools in browser, there will be tab called provider which will show all active providers and its data